# Custom teams app not visible in teams call

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have uploaded a teams app in my organization and it is visible and playable if I access teams (as shown in screenshot below)
[image: CustomApp]

Now my colleague also can see it in his teams tab as well. But when we both do a call to each other, this app is missing from teams call.

[image: TeamsCall]

So my question is, why is it not visible in teams call "Apps" tab and how do I add it?

My manifest file is as follows:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "${{TEAMS_APP_ID}}",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Saif",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "App",
        "full": "App"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Short description of App",
        "full": "Full description of App"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [],
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "index0",
            "name": "Tab",
            "contentUrl": "https://myURL/index_DE.html", 
            "websiteUrl": "https://myURL/index_DE.html", 
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
"configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "URL",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupChat"
            ],
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "context": [
                "channelTab",
                "privateChatTab",
                "meetingChatTab",
                "meetingDetailsTab",
                "meetingSidePanel",
                "meetingStage"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "${{TAB_DOMAIN}}"
    ],
    "showLoadingIndicator": false
}
```

Comment: In order to make your app usable in Microsoft Teams meetings, enable your apps for Teams meetings and configure the apps to be available in the meeting scope within their app manifest. For more details follow this below doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/build-tabs-for-meeting?tabs=desktop%2Cmeeting-chat-view-desktop%2Cmeeting-side-panel%2Cmeeting-stage-view-desktop%2Cchannel-meeting-desktop#enable-your-tabs-for-teams-meeting

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT thanks for your response, I have added my manifest file, can you please tell me where do I add my configurableTabs and how do I set it?

Comment: Please refer below doc which explains how to configure tab app for a meeting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/build-tabs-for-meeting?tabs=desktop%2Cmeeting-chat-view-desktop%2Cmeeting-side-panel%2Cmeeting-stage-view-desktop%2Cchannel-meeting-desktop#configure-tab-app-for-a-meeting  PFB example of sample manifest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#sample-manifest

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I have added configuration data to manifest file and updated my code as given above. I dont understand what configuration URL is? Can you explain what I have to provide here?

Comment: `configurationUrl` is the https:// URL to use when configuring the tab. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#configurabletabs and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT you have just been providing links, can you atleast post an html code example for config file ?

Comment: Can't add html code in comment section. Thats the reason was providing the reference link so that you can get it from there.

Comment: Anyway, let me add complete code in 'Answer' section.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your app usable in Microsoft Teams meetings, enable your apps for Teams meetings and configure the apps to be available in the meeting scope within their app manifest.

Apps in meetings can use the following contexts: `meetingChatTab`, `meetingDetailsTab`, `meetingSidePanel`, and `meetingStage`. After a meeting participant installs an app and configures the tab in meeting, all the targeted other contexts of the app for the given meeting starts to render the tab.

The following code snippet is an example of a configurable tab used in an app for Teams meetings:

```
"configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://contoso.com/teamstab/configure",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "context":[
        "channelTab",
        "privateChatTab",
        "meetingChatTab",
        "meetingDetailsTab",
        "meetingSidePanel",
        "meetingStage"
     ]
    }
  ]
```

A configuration page is a special type of content page. The following code is an example for the configuration page:

[image]

```
<head>
    <script src="https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.2.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384yBjE++eHeBPzIg+IKl9OHFqMbSdrzY2S/LW3qeitc5vqXewEYRWegByWzBN/chRh" 
      crossorigin="anonymous" >
    </script>
<body>
    <button onclick="(document.getElementById('icon').src = '/images/iconGray.png'); colorClickGray()">Select Gray</button>
    <img id="icon" src="/images/teamsIcon.png" alt="icon" style="width:100px" />
    <button onclick="(document.getElementById('icon').src = '/images/iconRed.png'); colorClickRed()">Select Red</button>

    <script>
        await microsoftTeams.app.initialize();
        let saveGray = () => {
            microsoftTeams.pages.config.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
                const configPromise = pages.config.setConfig({
                    websiteUrl: "https://yourWebsite.com",
                    contentUrl: "https://yourWebsite.com/gray",
                    entityId: "grayIconTab",
                    suggestedDisplayName: "MyNewTab"
                });
                configPromise.
                    then((result) => {saveEvent.notifySuccess()}).
                    catch((error) => {saveEvent.notifyFailure("failure message")});
            });
        }

        let saveRed = () => {
            microsoftTeams.pages.config.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
                const configPromise = pages.config.setConfig({
                    websiteUrl: "https://yourWebsite.com",
                    contentUrl: "https://yourWebsite.com/red",
                    entityId: "redIconTab",
                    suggestedDisplayName: "MyNewTab"
                });
                configPromise.
                    then((result) => {saveEvent.notifySuccess();}).
                    catch((error) => {saveEvent.notifyFailure("failure message")});
            });
        }

        let gr = document.getElementById("gray").style;
        let rd = document.getElementById("red").style;

        const colorClickGray = () => {
            gr.display = "block";
            rd.display = "none";
            microsoftTeams.pages.config.setValidityState(true);
            saveGray()
        }

        const colorClickRed = () => {
            rd.display = "block";
            gr.display = "none";
            microsoftTeams.pages.config.setValidityState(true);
            saveRed();
        }
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2

Meeting apps sample reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/build-tabs-for-meeting?tabs=desktop%2Cmeeting-chat-view-desktop%2Cmeeting-side-panel%2Cmeeting-stage-view-desktop%2Cchannel-meeting-desktop#code-sample

Comment: The "Save" button is never enabled even after I press one of the two buttons. Is it needed to have a configure html file? Won't it be better to just go to web link provided?

Comment: The meeting app capabilities are supported only with `configurableTabs`. It won't support `staticTabs`.